# CSS Stylesheet(s) not loading after a domain change

Tags: html, css, dns, server

We recently transferred to a new off site hosted website.  Due to needing to access our old site still we created an internal access only sub-domain, (ex. http://oldsite.domain.com).  The style sheets are relative paths and they worked flawlessly when we were still using http://www.domain.com.

Now under the oldsite sub-domain the CSS stylesheets will not load, or even at times randomly load partially.

Has anyone experienced this issue?  If so can anyone assist in locating some steps for troubleshooting or even resolution?  I've been researching this for over a week now with little luck finding how a domain change could effect the relative path css stylesheets.

Comment: Check the `Network` tab in Chrome devtools for any errors to actually see how t he relative paths are being rendered.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at this as well.  It actually didn't report the CSS complications for some reason and I ended up having to go into the web.config file and adding an entry to reflect the domain changes.